# Xcode 6: create new Objective C file messed up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I've got *Xcode 6 beta 6* and just wanted to add a new Class to my project.

Now, it is File -> New File -> Objective-C File and I have to choose between Empty File, Category, Protocol and Extension. I just want to make a new class (say *HelloWorld*) which inherits from let's say `NSObject`.

Normally the Xcode creates the `.m` file and auto-creates the `.h` file, but now it has only created the `.m` file, named *NSObject_HelloWorld.m*. No header file has been created and I don't want the naming scheme with *Superclass_newClass* either.

Did I miss something?

Comment: something got screwed up, sometimes you cant see the files in xcode, so use finder to get to your project and delete them , and start over fresh

Comment: you should have chosen the _Cocoa Touch Class_ instead, then you can choose the language i.e. _Objective-C_, and everything is just happening as it has been happening before.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

everything is the quite similar to what was before, but here is the procedure in *Xcode6 beta6*:

## #1

choose the `New` and `File...` or press <kbd>⌘N</kbd> on keyboard:

[image: new]

---

## #2

choose *iOS*, *Source* then *Cocoa Touch Class*:

[image: Cocoa Touch Class]

---

## #3

type the name of your new class (e.g. *HelloWorldClass*), it is a subset of the `NSObject`, and you need to choose the *Language* as well:

[image: HelloWorldClass]

## #4

after you saved the files, you can find them in the *Project Navigator* like I did:

[image: Project Navigator]

Comment: Was confused about this as well. This explains it perfectly.

Comment: And for OSX Cocoa apps, select OS X, then select `Cocoa Class` (rather than Objective-C File), and Xcode 6 will generate both the .m and .h files.